# Add transform property (scale) without changing previous transform property (translate3d)

Tags: css

As you can see at the top part of the picture, there is a css line given to the element itself -> `transform: translate3d(681px, 407px, 0px);`

I would like to add a property `scale` to the transform but it just overwrites the `translate3d`

I know I can put these 2 after eachother like this: `transform: translate3d(681px, 407px, 0px) scale(2);` But I can't use this as the number in translate3d are random and there is no way for me of knowing them.

Is there any way I can still use the `scale` property without ruining the `translate3d` ?

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's sadly not possible using the transform property.

But you can use the standalone `scale` property for this, once it is supported by all major browsers. Browser support is really poor at the moment.

https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_scale

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know! I've managed to get a workaround for my problem and just scaled the child element of it. I will keep an eye on the ```scale``` property.